# Constantly getting new PSQL log notifications; no changes were made

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-nodejs

My logs just started showing these messages constantly:

`[ROSE] [13-1]  sql_error_code = 00000 time_ms = "2022-05-10 20:34:02.227 UTC" pid="66624" proc_start_time="2022-05-10 20:33:48 UTC" session_id="627acc2c.10440" vtid="" tid="0" log_line="1" database="{db_name}" connection_source="{ip_address}(52448)" user="{db_user_name}" application_name="[unknown]" LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:13.342 user={db_user_name} database={db_name} host={ip_address} port=52448`

I haven't made any changes. sometimes the application name is specified as "Heroku Postgres - Monitoring." Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Seeing this too in our app. No changes, and no idea exactly what is going on. Probably need to take it up with Heroku.

Comment: @DrewMcCormack - it sure looks like just benign log messages, but for some reason, they cannot be turned off. It's all very odd.

Comment: My app is still working fine. I think in my case at least, it is because we close connections often. It seems Heroku probably increased their log level, so that every disconnection is logged. So probably harmless, though perhaps we should rethink our connection strategy.

Comment: I too am seeing this quite a lot on all my postgres instances for all apps I am running on Heorku. My application is performing as normal but this specific log message gets spammed at me a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notified Heroku about this and they assured me that this log message is an oversight in a latest update they made to their postgres logging systems. There is no need for concern.

Apparently this will be remedied soon

[Here is a relevant Heroku Issue page regarding the matter](https://help.heroku.com/CRX2JK11/why-am-i-getting-sql_error_code-00000-in-my-postgresql-logs-is-this-an-error-from-my-queries)